# When to use Dispose

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've recently started developing with **ASP.NET MVC** and some examples I've found override the `Dispose()` method in the base controllers but most do not.

What is the point of `Dispose` and when should it be overridden and when is it not necessary

Comment: Typically you don't need to worry about it in your controller. An IoC container will manage disposing your controllers and injected resources for you.

Comment: You'll find plenty of questions (and answers) about the Dispose pattern here on SO. Long story short: It's meant to deterministic give back used resources (simplest example: close an opened file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general in .net you need to implement IDisposable if your class are creating any IDisposable objects and storing them as instance variables/properties. There are possible exceptions to this rule. But the point with IDisposable is to clean up system resources the garbage collector can't by itself.

So if your class is creating IDisposables, it also need to make sure they are cleaned up. Either by `using(someDisposableChildObject){}` directly or through implementing IDisposable and calling `someDisposableChildObject.Dispose()` in the Dispose method.

Comment: I have very little experience with COM but from the little I do know, don't all COM object inherit IDisposable? If so, then from your answer, it functions like a destructor in c++ and should therefore be good practice to override it unless you have good reason not to?

Comment: In normal classes you can't "override" dispose as it's not part of object. In those cases it would mean to implement IDisposable which basically requires the consumer to do extra job (by disposing it).

In the case of the controller, overriding without calling the base.Dispose would probably be bad. And unless you have disposable object you want to dispose it's a waste of time to do it. But it will not hurt as long as you still call the base.